# How does AWS API Gateway parses multiple value query parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-api-gateway, query-string, url-parameters

I was working on exposing an API on API Gateway, but observed that the query parameters forwarded by API Gateway are not what I was expecting.

Let's say I wanted to request following URL: `GET "https://cloud.domain.com/api/endpoint?param=%5B%27Param1%27%2C%27Param2%27%2C%27Param3%27%2C%27Param4%27%5D"`

Where `param` is a query parameter which holds URL encoded value of `['Param1','Param2','Param3','Param4']`.

Now AWS Gateway forwarded this request to my service as follows: `GET "https://cloud.domain.com/api/endpoint?param=%5B'Param1','Param2','Param3','Param4'%5D"`.

I have also reffered to the following documentation of AWS: [Support for multi-value parameters in Amazon API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/support-for-multi-value-parameters-in-amazon-api-gateway/). But what I wanted to understand is, what API Gateway is actually doing with query parameters? By observation, I thought of it as a partial URL decoding where only specific characters have been decoded (`'` and `,`) and others are left as it is.

I wanted help to understand how this parsing is working. Thank you!

Summary: I tried to pass multiple values query parameters to API exposed on API Gateway with expectations of getting same request at service. While it arrived as partially URL decoded request. I want to understand how API Gateway processes the request query parameters.